# Is there a way in Java to pop an Integer object out of an arrayList and then place it in another arrayList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

For example, myArrayList is [1, 1, 1], is there a function which removes a 1 from myArray and then places it in myArrayList2 so that:

myArrayList [1, 1]
myArrayList2 [1]

Comment: Your question asks about array, but you tagged ArrayList, which is a totally different data structure. Do you want to know for array (where this is not really possible), or for ArrayList (where you could do this with some coding)?

Comment: For an _array_, no. They are fixed-size, and can only have their internal references/values set to new ones. A _List_ (i.e. an object, for example ArrayList) can hold a variable amount, and some even have the `#pop` and `#push` methods from `Queue<T>` (e.g. `LinkedList`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, yes I meant for Lists and ArrayLists. Let me change my question as I meant that

Comment: @Rogue, is it only LinkedLists which have pop and push?

Comment: You could just remove the element with the index. e.g. `myArrayList1.remove(2)` would remove the third element. Then you can simply add it to the other list.

Comment: An [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has the `get`, `remove`, and `set` methods.

Comment: @Alexander those methods are inherited from the [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface (not `Queue`, and it may have also used `Stack` in the past, my bad...). Deque meaning "double ended queue", it basically combines the operations of queues and stack data structures to allow those methods. Be mindful of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and prefer to use `List` or `Deque` as your variable types instead of `ArrayList`/`ArrayDeque`/`LinkedList` etc. This will make your code use common ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. For any *mutable* `List`, you could use the `listIterator()`:

To remove from the front:

```java
private static void moveGeneralList() {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list1.listIterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        list2.add(iterator.next());
        iterator.remove();
    }

    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println(list2);
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
[1]
```

To remove from the end:

```java
private static void moveGeneralListReversed() {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list1.listIterator(list1.size());
    if (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
        list2.add(iterator.previous());
        iterator.remove();
    }

    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println(list2);
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
[3]
```

You can also use `LinkedList`/`Deque` specific methods like `pop` to remove from the start of the list:

```java
private static void linkedListPop() {
    LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    list2.add(list1.pop());

    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println(list2);
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
[1]
```

And other combinations are possible, of course (e.g. using `removeLast()`, `addFirst()` (when using a `Deque`), etc.).

Doing this with an immutable list will result in an exception (`UnsupportedOperationException`).